# Is there a way to implement relay-style cursor based pagination in Posgresql?

Tags: postgresql, pagination, graphql, typeorm, relay

I'm trying to find a way to implement the relay-style cursor based pagingation using Postgresql. In this scheme, I would order my results based on certain criteria on a number of columns. After I get the results, I would use the columns values for each retrieved record to build a cursor for each record.

My question is:

If I have a record with column values such as this:

```
[ { lastName: "Turing", age: "50", id: "100" } ]
```

and it was retrieved with an order such as this:

```
[ { lastName: "asc", age: "desc", id: "asc" } ]
```

If I save this criteria and ordering by which a record was retrieved, is it possible to get all the results that would come after the record in this ordering even if the given record itself was deleted?

I was thinking to use the rank(), but I think it breaks paging when records are deleted.

Comment: This is only possible (logically) if nothing writes to the table between reads. If that is the case then this is trivial. What exactly is your question.